# Can you use ADODB to connect Excel to Azure SQL Server DW?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to run a simple query from Excel to newer version of SQL Server.  I have done this many times in the past, but it was always to a standard SQL Server DB.  Now, I'm working with a new animal, which is Azure SQL Server Data Warehouse.  I am using very generic VBA code to connect to the DW.

```
Sub TryMe()

'Initializes variables
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String

pswd = "my_pwd"
user = "my_used_ID"
dbName = "my_DB_name"
server = "server_name.database.Windows.net"

'Setup the connection string for accessing MS SQL database
   'Make sure to change:
       '1: PASSWORD
       '2: USERNAME
       '3: REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS
       '4: DATABASE
    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Password=pswd;User ID=user;Data Source=server;Use Encryption for Data=False;Initial Catalog=dbname"

    'Opens connection to the database
    cnn.Open ConnectionString
    'Timeout error in seconds for executing the entire query; this will run for 15 minutes before VBA timesout, but your database might timeout before this value
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

    'This is your actual MS SQL query that you need to run; you should check this query first using a more robust SQL editor (such as HeidiSQL) to ensure your query is valid
    StrQuery = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM myBigTable"

    'Performs the actual query
    rst.Open StrQuery, cnn
    'Dumps all the results from the StrQuery into cell A2 of the first sheet in the active workbook
    Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
End Sub
```

It should be a pretty straightforward thing, but I keep getting an error message that says: 'SQL Server does not exist or access is denied'.

The error occurs on this line:

```
cnn.Open ConnectionString
```

I set a reference to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.0 Library`.

Has anyone tried this and actually gotten this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not pasting in the variables to the connection string.  And the old `SQLOLEDB` provider is too old to connect to Azure.  You'll need to install the new one from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56730).

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Password=" & pswd & ";User ID=" & user & ";Data Source=" & server & ";Use Encryption for Data=False;Initial Catalog=" & dbName & ""
```

If you don't want to install MSOLEDBSQL, you can use one of the [newer ODBC drivers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567). The connection string is a bit wierd, as you use the `OleDb Provider for ODBC Drivers`.  EG:

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL;Extended Properties=""Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};pwd=" & pswd & ";uid=" & user & ";Server=" & server & ";database=" & dbName & """"
```

Comment: I'm going with the second option because I don't want to have to install drivers.  I can certainly do it myself, but if I give this to anyone else, they probably won't know what to do.  So, when I get to this line of code: rst.Open StrQuery, cnn
I get an error about 'invalid object name'.  I know the name of the table object is correct.  I feel like it's hitting the wrong DB, but the name is right there and it's spelled correctly.  It's almost like it's going to the default 'master' DB, but I don't know how that's possible when I explicitly told it to look at the production DB.

Comment: It's actually going to the default 'master' DB, even though I'm telling it to go to the prod DB, which should be handled by the Initial Catalog reference, I thought.  Anyway, is there a setting that controls this, or some way around this?  Thanks.

Comment: The connection string was messed up, and it was connecting to Master.  The correct keyword for ODBC is `database` not `Initial Catalog` See edit.

Comment: Thanks, but now when I hit this line: cnn.Open ConnectionString
I get this error message: 'client driver version is not supported'.
I'm using Office 365 ProPlus.  When I look at my drivers, I see ODBC Driver 17for SQL Server, SQL Server, and SQL Server Native Client 11.0.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: I'm getting that too now.  It looks like you'll need to use one of the newer ODBC drivers. See edit.

Comment: Yeap, yeap!  It's working now.  I should have figured that out.  I saw that in my list of ODBC drivers, but I didn't pay much attention to it yesterday.  Thanks for the assist!!